# Logstash Processing Multi Line records from file

Tags: logstash, multiline

My log sample is something like this:

```
2017-01-03 03:38:18 +0000 field1: 123 field2: 321
field3: 1133 field4: 0901
2017-01-03 03:38:19 +0000 field1: 523 field2: 521
field3: 533 field4: 509
```

Im very new to this. How should I write the regex?

Comment: You didn't explictly say, but is the file being *read* locally by logstash, or are you using a shipper like filebeat?

Comment: The file is a local file. It is in the same drive as logstash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the file{} input, you should use the [multiline codec](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-codecs-multiline.html) (rather than the multiline{} filter), e.g.:

```
input {
  file {
    path => "..."
    codec => multiline {
      negate => "true"
      pattern => "^%{YEAR}"
      what => "previous"
    }
  }
}
```

Which you would read as, "if the line doesn't start with a year, keep it with the previous line".

Comment: so what does the '^' in the "^%{YEAR}" mean?

Comment: The caret means "begins with".  Getting the most out of logstash will require a good knowledge of regular expressions.